# What is the meaning of "scope" in a Smart Contract?

Tags: smart-contract, eosio-code, multi-index

Since I have read the tutorial. I don't understanding the following:

> Note that scopes are used to logically separate tables within a
>   multi-index (see the eosio.token contract multi-index for an example,
>   which scopes the table on the token owner). Scopes were originally
>   intended to separate table state in order to allow for parallel
>   computation on the individual sub-tables. However, currently
>   inter-blockchain communication has been prioritized over parallelism.
>   Because of this, scopes are currently only used to logically separate
>   the tables as in the case of eosio.token.

To my knowledge, scopes are only used by eosio.token. And not yet within multi-indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EOSIO organizes data in the fashion described in the graphic below.

[image: how EOSIO organizes data]

The scope usually refers to the account in relation to which the data is stored. So eosio.token stores each account's token balance in an accounts table. But instead of a single *huge* accounts table, each user's account is kept in a small table scoped to that user.

Shout out to the EverythingEOS developer courses for going over this stuff.